# Trying to send a C# array to Python and read it as a list

Tags: c#, python, arrays, cmd, arguments

So I'm making a GUI using WPF. All of the GUI interactions (selecting checkboxes, filling in textboxes, etc.) will be sent to a Python script as arguments and dictate what the python script will end up processing. For the most part, most of the data have a fixed amount of elements being passed, however, the last two pieces of data I am passing vary in size depending on what the user inputs (these variables being `frequencyDynamicList` and `frequencyIndexList`). What would be the best way to send these arrays as arguments?

```
private static void run(string path, int[] temperatureList, int[] dataList, float[] toggleData, int toggleEnable, int[] bandEnable, List<string> frequencyDynamicList, List<int> frequencyIndexList)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    //startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/c \"python ProcessDataGUI.py\"" + " "
                              + path + " "
                              + temperatureList[0] + " " + temperatureList[1] + " " + temperatureList[2] + " " + temperatureList[3] + " " + temperatureList[4] + " "
                              + dataList[0] + " " + dataList[1] + " " + dataList[2] + " " + dataList[3] + " " + dataList[4] + " " + dataList[5] + " " + dataList[6] + " "
                              + toggleData[0] + " " + toggleData[1] + " " + toggleData[2] + " " + toggleData[3] + " " + toggleData[4] + " " + toggleData[5] + " " + toggleData[6] + " "
                              + toggleEnable + " "
                              + bandEnable[0] + " " + bandEnable[1] + " " + bandEnable[2] + " "
                              + frequencyDynamicList.ToArray() + " " + frequencyIndexList.ToArray();
    p.StartInfo = startInfo;
    p.Start();
}
```

Comment: Embedding Python would eliminate the overhead of starting a new process. https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you to use a class rather than independent variables.

```
private class MyData {
    int[] TemperatureList { get; set; }
    int[] DataList { get; set; }
    float[] ToggleData { get; set; }
    int ToggleEnable { get; set; }
    int[] BandEnable { get; set; }
    List<string> FrequencyDynamicList { get; set; }
    List<int> FrequencyIndexList { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use the following code:

```
private static void run(string path, MyData myData)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            //startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/c \"python ProcessDataGUI.py\"" + " "
                                  + path + " "
                                  + string.Join(" ", myData.TemperatureList.Cast<int>().ToList()) + " "
                                  + string.Join(" ", myData.DataList.Cast<int>().ToList()) + " "
                                  + string.Join(" ", myData.ToggleData.Cast<float>().ToList()) + " "
                                  + toggleEnable + " "
                                  + string.Join(" ", myData.BandEnable.Cast<int>().ToList()) + " "
                                  + string.Join(" ",FrequencyDynamicList); + " " 
                                  + string.Join(" ",FrequencyIndexList);
            p.StartInfo = startInfo;
            p.Start();
        }
```